# kendo-treeview inside the kendo grid angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular9, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown

I have a   `kendo-treeview` in angular 9 , I want to add `kendo-treeview` inside a drop down same as rad combo treeview in asp.net

I searched for the solution in Kendo site without success

How can I implement in Angular 2+

Answer (score 0):

I did this at work, so can't really get you some code unfortunately.

I used a button to open a popup like in their basic example [Kendo UI popup](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/popup/).
I then put the treeView inside that popup

Fair warning - it may take a few hours to create it